# Reiniciar todos los ID de una BBDD MySql

Tags: mysql

Un saludo cordial para todos.

Tengo una base de datos MySQL la cual administro desde PHPMyAdmin, también tengo acceso vía workbench. ¿De qué manera puedo reiniciar la Base de Datos para que todos los ID autonuméricos empiecen nuevamente desde 1?, he estado haciendo pruebas sobre la BBDD, pero no quiero tener que eliminar y crear nuevamente.

Comment: La pregunta es.. con que necesidad? es importante saber eso.. mas alla de eso, ahora buscamos una respuesta?

Comment: Ah y porfa, aclaras si es alguna version en especial de mysql?

Comment: Ya cree la base de datos, la tengo conectada con un sistema que diseñé y está funcionando, hemos estado haciendo pruebas, ahora queremos comenzar con la información real.... por eso quiero que todos los ID vuelvan a cero.

Comment: Si haces un truncate de la tabla esto reinicia el autonumerico de cada tabla. Mas alla de eso, no deberia importar nunca el id de los campos, ya que el usuario no los ve. Y como si fuera poco, tu base de test no puede ser nunca igual a tu base de produccion. Donde vas a hacer futuros test? Creo que tenes un problema de arquitectura aca. A prod deberia ir una base nueva.

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si estas respuestas han aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enfatizando lo que ha aportado @gbianchi:

- no debería importarte el valor de los autonuméricos, únicamente que sean diferentes
- un `TRUNCATE TABLE` deja los id a 1
- y no debes mezclar desarrollo con producción

La instrucción de MySQL que estás buscando, para cada tabla, es:

```
ALTER TABLE tabla AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Con esta otra query puedes obtener el nombre de todas las tablas de tu base de datos:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='stackoverflow';
```

Answer (score 0):

Desde la pestaña "operaciones" en el phpMyAdmin hay un input que dice "auto_increment", tenés que poner ahí un "1".

Comment: ¿Esa acción me reiniciará todos los ID?

Comment: No. Esto solo sirve para decir de cuanto es el incremento de cada autonumerico. No tiene nada que ver.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMonsalve empezará a correr de nuevo en "1" el campo autoincrementable!